# Readthedocs mock not working with Matplolitb

Tags: read-the-docs

Read the Docs will not build docs for my package because it includes matplotlib.
I used the code [on their website](https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html) to mock out matplotlib, but still the build fails because freetype and png are required to build matplotlib, and apparently this is not installed on their machine.
I tried with and without building in the virtualenv.

[Here](https://github.com/CorySimon/pyIAST/blob/master/docs/conf.py) is my config.py.

Why is my mock not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you have matplotlib in your requirements.txt, Read the Docs will still try to install it in the virtualenv. You have to take matplotlib (and anything else you want to mock) out of the requirements.

If you still want it in requirements.txt for setup but not for building the docs, I think you can specify a different requirements file (like docs/requirements.txt or something) in the ReadTheDocs Admin (under advanced settings).

I hope this solves your problem.